# SUM BY UNQIUE CUSTOMER and MONTH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I would like to calculate the sum of revenue by unique customers and by month.

I have used the following formula

```
=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(REVENUE,(REPORT_MONTH=C2))))
```

However this returns the sum of unique value in column reference 'REVENUE' which is not the end goal I would like.

I have the following columns and sample data:

| Report_Month | Customer code | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/07/2023 | 123 | 100 |
| 31/07/2023 | 123 | 100 |
| 31/08/2023 | 1234 | 1000 |
| 31/08/2023 | 12345 | 100 |

Expected output

| Month | Unique Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| Jul-23 | 100 |
| Aug-23 | 1100 |

Comment: It would help if you provide some sample data ([Markdown Table Generator])(https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) plus the expected output. Cl_Code = Customer code? Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: Where are the customers in your output? Why is the unique revenue 100 for Jul-23?

Comment: In my output i wanted aggregate of the month, but summed by unqiue customer codes. So Jul-23 would be 100 because the customer code appears twice in the month

Comment: What would you expect if there were an entry in August for 1234 with revenue 200? Or what would you expect if the second entry for July and 123 would have 200 as revenue? Should the formula take the first entry of a unique date/customer combination - or the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this should work for you:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A2:C5),
     b,INDEX(a,,1),
     c,INDEX(a,,3),
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     HSTACK(TEXT(ub,"mmm-yy"),MMULT(N(ub=TOROW(b)),c)))
```

---

If you need the header then, wrap within <kbd>VSTACK()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A2:C5),
     b,INDEX(a,,1),
     c,INDEX(a,,3),
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     VSTACK({"Month","Revenue"},
     HSTACK(TEXT(ub,"mmm-yy"),MMULT(N(ub=TOROW(b)),c))))
```

---

Comment: I will try this formula. Ive never used the let function before so will need to understand that also thank you

Comment: @Fazza `LET()` function is used to assign names for calculations its like a helper column, instead of repeating the same formulas more than once, we just used the variables here. To know more on it, recommended and suggested to read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:~:text=Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365%20Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365,apply%20within%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20LET%20function.)**

Answer (score 0):

Formula to fit to your scenario:

```
=MAP(Month,LAMBDA(m, SUM((EOMONTH(m,0)=Report_Month)*Revenue)))
```

But here is a one-stop-shop formula that outputs the entire report:

```
=LET(
    a, A3:C6,
    b, TAKE(a, , 1),
    c, MONTH(b),
    d, DROP(a, , 2),
    VSTACK(
        {"Month","Unique Revenue"},
        HSTACK(
            TEXT(UNIQUE(b), "y-mmm"),
            MAP(UNIQUE(c), LAMBDA(m, SUM((m = c) * d)))
        )
    )
)
```

[image]